# Crear Metodo o Funcion en CShrp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

les hago una consulta tal vez facil para algunos, tengo el sgte codigo en ***c#*** y quiero de esto poder comprimir y sacar una funcion pero no logro dar con los tipos de objeto y clases genericos q debo recibir para poder hacerlo.

```
switch (typeConsult)
            {
                case 1:
                    dataRango = db.Database.SqlQuery<TramaGpsMovRango>(string.Concat("SELECT TOP(1000) * FROM trama.TramaGpsMovRango WHERE ", imeiQuery, " DateTimeGPS between '", dateDesde, "' AND '", dateHasta, "' ORDER BY DateTimeGPS DESC"));

                    foreach (var item in dataRango)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.IdTrama, item.plateId, item.hstId, item.DateTimeGPS.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), item.DateTimeServer.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), item.Latitude, item.Longitude, item.Speed, item.Heading, item.Degrees, item.Altitude, item.Location, item.EventID, item.Event, item.Distance, item.GPSFix, item.PDI, item.Zones, item.FIRMWARE, item.DriverID, item.Ignition, item.LastOn, item.LastOff, item.Odometer, item.Estado, item.date_insert, item.estadoReg, item.satelite);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dataHistory = db.Database.SqlQuery<TramaGpsMovHistory>(string.Concat("SELECT TOP(1000) * FROM trama.TramaGpsMovHistory WHERE ", imeiQuery, " DateTimeGPS between '", dateDesde, "' AND '", dateHasta, "' ORDER BY DateTimeGPS DESC"));

                    foreach (TramaGpsMovHistory item in dataHistory)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.IdTrama, item.plateId, item.hstId, item.DateTimeGPS.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), item.DateTimeServer.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), item.Latitude, item.Longitude, item.Speed, item.Heading, item.Degrees, item.Altitude, item.Location, item.EventID, item.Event, item.Distance, item.GPSFix, item.PDI, item.Zones, item.FIRMWARE, item.DriverID, item.Ignition, item.LastOn, item.LastOff, item.Odometer, item.Estado, item.date_insert, item.estadoReg, item.satelite);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    dataRango = db.Database.SqlQuery<TramaGpsMovRango>(string.Concat("SELECT TOP(1000) * FROM trama.TramaGpsMovRango WHERE ", imeiQuery, " DateTimeGPS between '", dateDesde, "' AND '", dateHasta, "' ORDER BY DateTimeGPS DESC"));

                    foreach (TramaGpsMovRango item in dataRango)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.IdTrama, item.plateId, item.hstId, item.DateTimeGPS, item.DateTimeServer, item.Latitude, item.Longitude, item.Speed, item.Heading, item.Degrees, item.Altitude, item.Location, item.EventID, item.Event, item.Distance, item.GPSFix, item.PDI, item.Zones, item.FIRMWARE, item.DriverID, item.Ignition, item.LastOn, item.LastOff, item.Odometer, item.Estado, item.date_insert, item.estadoReg, item.satelite);
                    }
                    break;
            }
```

Ahora los foreach quiero sacarlos y volver una función q me reciba pues la clase y el la colección a recorrer.

Tengan en cuenta q la clase puede variar, quiero q quede algo asi.

```
private DataTable RecorrerDatos(TipoDeClase Clase, EInumerable<Generico> colecction){
    foreach (TipoDeClase item in colecction)
    {
      dt.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.IdTrama, item.plateId, item.hstId, item.DateTimeGPS.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), item.DateTimeServer.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), item.Latitude, item.Longitude, item.Speed, item.Heading, item.Degrees, item.Altitude, item.Location, item.EventID, item.Event, item.Distance, item.GPSFix, item.PDI, item.Zones, item.FIRMWARE, item.DriverID, item.Ignition, item.LastOn, item.LastOff, item.Odometer, item.Estado, item.date_insert, item.estadoReg, item.satelite);
                    }
```

}

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Puedes leerte algo acerca de las clases anónimas, quizá te funcione.  Puedes revisar [aqui](https://csharp.com.es/clases-anonimas/)

Comment: creo que en tu función además falta agregar en los parámetros al "dueño" de tu variable dt

Comment: @Samael bueno ya lei tu link, no es q diga de a mucho, igualmente gracias.  Christian Cuadro Betancur Si el dueño lo tengo mas arriba solo q no lo copie alli.